# How can I get "if true" result from two other functions and use it in a third function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple "if true" function where I need to get the result from two other currently working functions. I have been scouring SO and the internet to find nothing that actually works. I made two initial functions. The first one checks the date and the second checks the time. I want this third script to check to see if the other two functions resulted in true and if so, do something. The script is as follows:

```js
$(function() {
  // attempted global variables but this did not work
  //var dateA = $('#startdate').val();
  //var dateB = $('#enddate').val();    
  //var timeA = $('#starttime').val();
  //var timeB = $('#endtime').val();        

  //This function appears to work
  $("#startdate, #enddate").on("change.apple", function() {
    var dateA = $('#startdate').val();
    var dateB = $('#enddate').val();


    if (((dateA).length && (dateB).length) && (dateA == dateB)) {
      alert("Apple");
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });

  //This function appears to work
  $("#starttime, #endtime").on("change.banana", function() {
    var timeA = $('#starttime').val();
    var timeB = $('#endtime').val();


    if (((timeA).length && (timeB).length) && (timeA >= timeB)) {
      alert("Banana");
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });



  //This function does NOT work
  $("#startdate, #enddate, #starttime, #endtime").change(function() {
    if (apple() && banana()) {
      // when its true
      alert("Hello");
    } else {
      // when its false
      alert("Goodbye");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <p><input type="text" id="startdate"></p>
      </li>

      <li>
        <p><input type="text" id="starttime" </p>
      </li>

      <li>
        <p><input type="text" id="enddate" </p>
      </li>

      <li>
        <p><input type="text" id="endtime"></p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

I cleaned up the code for this question so it can be inspected easily. I have tried using global variables but for some reason I can not get the inner function to view the external variables. I have tried to check for errors in naming and and possible incorrect placement but I can not seem to locate the problem. Can anybody assist me in getting this script to work? I am lost at this point. Thanks

Comment: Can you share some of the html as well? on need for css

Comment: Probably there is a reason why they must to be 2 different handlers, right?

Comment: `.on("change.apple", ...)` does not create a global function named `apple`. `apple` is known only inside jQuery, and it can be passed to `.off` method to rermove that particular listener.

Comment: @Teemu if you meant to me, I meant in product wise.

Comment: Anonymous functions can only be called where they are defined. You need to use a named function and use those as handlers. On the other hand, your functions all execute on very similar events, maybe it is fruitful to handle them all in one listener

Comment: You got a few unnecessary parentheses there... `(dateA).length === dateA.length` for instance, and `((dateA).length && (dateB).length) && (dateA == dateB)` is the same as `dateA.length && dateB.length && dateA == dateB`. If it helps you read the different conditions, by all means, keep them in there!

Comment: @user3154108 thanks for the input. Can you give me more information on how to do that? Thanks

Comment: Hogan posted an answer that pretty much picks that all up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for your reference i share this instead of return boolean values send it as string

and change conditions according to your need and pass those string values into the third

condition you want

//Updated the code as per change function if you want to execute the condition 
  based on length then you can get the length value before the if condition no 
  need to complicate it with inside the if conditon

Try the third condition like function.To avoid the unwanted confusion make sure 
  every field is compulsory

```js
var valid_apple;
    var valid_banana;
    var dateA;
    var dateB;
    var timeA;
    var timeB;
  //This function appears to work
  $("#startdate, #enddate").on("change.apple",function() {
    dateA = $('#startdate').val().length;
    dateB = $('#enddate').val().length;

    if(dateA == dateB){
      alert("Apple");
      valid_apple ="true";
    }else{
      valid_apple ="false";
    }
  });

  //This function appears to work
  $("#starttime, #endtime").on("change.banana", function() {
    timeA = $('#starttime').val().length;
    timeB = $('#endtime').val().length;

    if(timeA!='' && timeB!=''){
    if(timeA >= timeB){
      alert("Banana");
      valid_banana = "true";
      third_fun();
    } else {
      valid_banana = "false";
      third_fun();
    }
  }
});


  function third_fun(){
    if(valid_apple == "true" && valid_banana == "true"){
      //when its true
      alert("Hello");
    }else{
      //when its false
      alert("Goodbye");
    }
  }
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <p><input type="text" id="startdate" placeholder="startdate"></p>
      </li>

      <li>
        <p><input type="text" id="starttime" placeholder="starttime"></p>
      </li>

      <li>
        <p><input type="text" id="enddate" placeholder="enddate"> </p>
      </li>

      <li>
        <p><input type="text" id="endtime" placeholder="endtime"></p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Hello @ayyappa can you expand this to show how to implement the change functions? Thanks

Comment: Hello @ayyappa thanks for the update. I was able to modify your code to get things to work perfect. I think what helped the most was passing a string to the third function. I am not sure why passing a string works while passing a boolean does not. For my comprehension can you explain why? Thanks.

Comment: Boolean values are meant to be return true or false.So we have to return those values into another function where we want..while sending values it should be a function then only you can receive it as a response.Which not worked out for us..so here we go with strings...the advantage we have with strings,we can declare it as a global variable and store the string values into it and we can use it where ever we want..

Comment: Hello @ayyappa, thanks for your answer. I will work with it more so I can understand it better. Would you happen to know how to address the double digit numbers like "12" in this code? For example "starttime = 12pm" shows as later than "endtime=10pm". Obviously 12pm is before 10pm, but numerically 10 comes before 12. Does that make any sense? I need the numbers like "12" to behave as if they are younger than the times that come after. Can you think of a way? I was thinking to somehow change/convert them to 24 hour time format behind the scenes while keeping 12 hour time visible to the user.

Answer (score 1):

just make the named functions -- like this:

```
$(function() {
  // attempted global variables but this did not work
  //var dateA = $('#startdate').val();
  //var dateB = $('#enddate').val();    
  //var timeA = $('#starttime').val();
  //var timeB = $('#endtime').val();        

 function apple() {
    var dateA = $('#startdate').val();
    var dateB = $('#enddate').val();


    if (((dateA).length && (dateB).length) && (dateA == dateB)) {
      alert("Apple");
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  //This function appears to work
  $("#startdate, #enddate").on("change.apple", apple);

  function banana() {
    var timeA = $('#starttime').val();
    var timeB = $('#endtime').val();


    if (((timeA).length && (timeB).length) && (timeA >= timeB)) {
      alert("Banana");
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }


  //This function appears to work
  $("#starttime, #endtime").on("change.banana", banana );

  //This function does NOT work
  $("#startdate, #enddate, #starttime, #endtime").change(function() {
    if (apple() && banana()) {
      // when its true
      alert("Hello");
    } else {
      // when its false
      alert("Goodbye");
    }
  });
});
```

> There is no magic to using anonymous functions... you can just use named ones instead.

Comment: Hello @Hogan, thanks for the assistance. I tried your script and it is not firing correctly. I am not sure what the problem is but every input made fires alerts. Do you know why? Do you think it could be something with these change functions?

Comment: @kejo -- that is how code is written -- on every change alert hello or goodbye. -- This is working as expected.  Looking at the answer you accepted clearly the original code you gave was not what you wanted.

Comment: Hello @Hogan, for some reason none of the change functions worked as expected...nothing was being compared. All the alerts were firing at all times, not just my third function. If I removed the "alert("Goodbye") from the third function all alerts were still firing at all times. I did not mean to offend you in any way. I do apologize if that were the case.

Comment: @kejo -- ok then I would have to see what code you used.